# Magento: How to prevent page-load when required option validation fails?

Tags: jquery, validation, magento

I have configurable products on my Magento store and Size is a required option. When a user doesn't select the size and adds the product to cart, the page reloads and the error message is shown "Please specify product option(s)".

I want to prompt the user right there with "this is required field" message via jQuery if the required option is not selected and avoid the whole page reload thing.

How do I implement this?
Thanks!

P.S. I have a ajax add-to-cart enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

I have 2 method for this.

1. Adding `class="validate-select"` and edit the js/prototype/validation.js to have customize alert (default is "Please select an option.")
2. Add an onChange on the select box inside configurable.phtml (template/catalog/product/view/type/options), and disable the button if the option are null.

```js
//last is used if there is more than 1 option, when you change the first option, you have to select the second option.
function changeBox(value,last) {
   if(last == "") {
    jQuery('#buttonCart').attr('disabled','disabled');   
   }
   if(value == "") {
    jQuery('#buttonCart').attr('disabled','disabled');
    
   } else {
    if(last == "") {   
    jQuery('#buttonCart').attr('disabled','disabled'); 
    } else {   
    jQuery('#buttonCart').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
   }   
  }
```

```html
<select id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry" onchange="changeBox(this.value,'<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?>last<?php } else { echo ""; }?>')">
<option><?php echo $this->__('Select '.$_attribute->getLabel()) ?></option>
</select>
```

And don't forget to give the id in the add to cart button `id="buttonCart"`

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue mentioned in the question: "the page reloads and the error message is shown". The page still reloads if no size is selected when you click add-to-cart.

Comment: @thdoan we have same issue facing after upgrade but not founding solution for that can you suggest me please thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can you jQuery for client side validation. Provide the class to the dropdown and on the button click event(i.e on click "Add to Cart"). you can use simple validation of that dropdown.

You could use something like this

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#addtocart').on('click',function(e) {
        if ($('.myDropdown').val() == '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Please select anyone");
        }
    });
});
```

Here **#addtocart** is the id of your add to cart button (may vary according to you) and **.myDropdown** is the class that you will provide to your dropdown.

Hope you got some idea about what to do.This may not be the exact code but this somehow gives you the overview to proceed further.

Hope this will help.